# jsPDF - Exactly capture a html page to PDF

Tags: html, css, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I need a table to be printed as a pdf and not to dismiss the css tied to the table.  I am also using angularjs.  I am looking at different ways and I am experimenting with jsPDF.

On the main page (rollup.html), I have the link that should export the table as a pdf.

```
<a style="float: right;"  href="genPDF()">PDF TEST</a>
```

In the js (rollup.js) within the controller, I have the genPDF function that should display whatever is included within the id #testDiv.

```
app.controller('Rollup', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, headersvc, locFiltersvc) {
....
function genPDF(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("testDiv"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG',20,20);
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        }
    });
}
});
```

Of course I assigned the testDiv to the div containing the table i want printed (which is located in route.html)

```
<div class="content-div" style="overflow: visible;" id="testDiv">
....
</div>
```

I have another button that works for the remaining tabs using a ng-click and broadcasts data from other tables that were simplier with no css.  Not sure if I should try to print the table using a ng-click and broadcasting the table data but with all the css as well.

```
        <li style="float: right;">      
            <button ng-click="printDiv('rollup-tab')">Printer Friendly</button>
        </li>
```

No errors were shown in the console for the jsPDF method, so not sure what the issue is. Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend looking into jsPDF - AutoTable library on GitHub via this [link](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable). I recently ran into a very similar scenario to yours and found maintaining CSS is difficult in this case. This solution is perfect for many use cases and solved my issue far more efficiently and effectively than relying on jsPDF on its own. Hope this helps!

Comment: The tutorial I have been following was [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJOfCnoqShw) This shows how to take a snap shot of the html to print as a pdf using jsPDF, but didnt seem to work for me.  The method you send me seems like I have to recreate the entire table with the user input and css.

Comment: I did personally look into the option that you would prefer to use, yet there are drawbacks that are related to the CSS and choice of browsers that will ultimately determine the output to the PDF document. The jsPDF AutoTable library is a much more fluid approach and ensures you're content is laid out correctly regardless of the limitations identified. Although this is extra work, it does pay off in the end and is more manageable in the long term.